# Powershell Remotely Delete PKI Certificates

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, certificate-authority, pki

I recently rebuilt my PKI and I would like to delete the certificates that were issued to all client machines across my network. Sounds like a job for Powershell! So I wrote this script to be distributed by GPO, ran from SysVol, and triggered on client machines at startup:

```
set-location cert:\LocalMachine\My
$certname = $env:COMPUTERNAME + ".domain.com"
get-item * | %{
if($_.issuer -like "CN=IssuingCA*" -and $_.DnsNameList.unicode -like $certname) { remove-item .\$_.Thumbprint -Force }
}
```

From an elevated command prompt:

- When Ran, the script gives no output (simply a new terminal line). It
  returns no errors and the Certificate is not deleted.
- When the argument `-WhatIf` is added to the `Remove-Item` command in
  the script, again no errors and the Certificate is not deleted.
- When Remove-Item .\CERTIFICATE-THUMBPRINT -Force is ran, the
  certificate is deleted.

Is this a permissions issue?
Is there a smarter/simpler way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try `remove-item -whatif` ??

Comment: @BigHomie. Yes, I tried that. I seem to have removed that information in an edit...

Comment: In your conditional codeblock, add in a `write-host` to dump something on the screen if the conditional is true.  I'm wondering if the script is evaluating as false (would explain the no error and no action).

Comment: @Colyn1337 Yep. It is evaluating True.

Comment: @ByronC. What happens if the codeblock is just `Remove-Item -Force`?

Comment: Please try "remove-item "$(Get-Location)\$($_.Thumbprint)" -Force -WhatIf"

Comment: Both suggestions simply end without deleting the cert. I have however found a 'Smarter/Simpler' way of doing it. Although I am still curious about the script....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answer is for the "Is there a smarter/simpler way to do this?" part of your question.  This script was successful in removing a go daddy cert for me

```
$Path = 'Cert:\LocalMachine\AuthRoot\'
$CertList = @()

$CertList = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path | Where-Object {$_.Issuer -like "CN=GO*"}

foreach($Cert in $CertList){
    remove-item "$($Path)$($Cert.Thumbprint)" -Force -WhatIf
}
```

I added a `-WhatIf` so that this code wasn't dangerous for the "copy\paste\run" folx.  Now, you'll need to adapt the `$Path`, `Where-Object`, and add the `$certname` variable, but the above template should have you going.

Answer (score 3):

Although I have not been able to solve the issue with the script, [I was able to find a 'Smarter/Simpler' way to achieve my goal](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771246.aspx).

From the Certificate Authority:

- Rt-Click `Certificate Templates` and select `Manage`
- Rt-Click the Certificate Template you wish to replace and select `Reenroll All Certificate Holders`

This will increment the Version number of the template and network systems with auto-enroll will delete the old cert and enroll with the new cert.

Though this requires auto-enrollment for the specific template I am working with, a solution to the script posted would be a preferable answer.